# Voltage to current circuit at high frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier

I try to implement a voltage to current circuit to drive a diode by a sweeping current. My idea is to use a RC circuit with a PWM as input, which create a sweeping voltage (an RC curve is good), and convert this voltage to current. To do so, I use the following voltage to current circuit using a TLE2141CP op amp, powered by a single 5V supply.

On the shown circuit, I connect the output to the negative input for my debug, but the diode will be placed here, actually I just put a wire to check the circuit and I should observe Vout = Vin_negative = Vin_positive.

At a "low frequency" (100kHz), all is fine I observe Vout = Vin_negative, there is just a small pulse at the beginning of the signal as you can see, but it is actually not a problem for me:

[image]

But, if I increase the frequency if my RC circuit to 1MHz (PWM frequency multiplied by 10 and time constant of RC divided by 10, so that the curve of my RC signal looks exactly like the previous test but at higher frequency), the Vout signal looks strange:

[image]

I expect to see the RC curve at the output (like for 100kHz) but it is not the case, moreover the output signal reach 4V whereas my RC is 3.3V max.

Could you please to help me to understand what happens and how to fix it ?

Thank you very much !

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1UTI7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Did you try comparing the first phase of both waveforms at the same settings (e.g. timescale)? On which basis did you select the amplifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're operating the TLE2141 outside of its operating conditions.

The TLE2141 can't bring its output down to 0V in a single-supply configuration. It says so right on the first page of its [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2141-q1.pdf): The output can swing down to 0.1V in such a configuration.

The first page of the datasheet also tells us another very important fact: It has a saturation recovery time of 150ns.

These two facts mean the following for your circuit: While you're holding the input at 0V, the OpAmp is saturating as it's trying to bring its output down more than it's able to. Then, when the input voltage rises, it needs about 150ns to recover from saturation. During recovery, it'll output all kinds of weird voltage spikes and potentially oscillate as well, which is exactly what you're seeing. (The spike in your 100kHz test is caused by this, and the distorted waveform in your 1MHz test is as well - it's the same spike, just zoomed in.)

In a 5V single-supply configuration, the OpAmp's input voltage range is also limited to 2.7V, so you're driving the input beyond what the OpAmp can handle.

An easy fix to your saturation and input voltage range problems would be to operate the OpAmp with split supplies, i.e. +12V/-5V. However, even with that fixed, you have to keep in mind that the TLE2141 has a settling time of more than 300ns, which means that it's probably just too slow for your application.

Comment: Indeed after reading your comment it looks obvious. Thank you very much for your help !